# How can I update Xamarin.Forms Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite from v119.6 to v119.7?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I Updated my nuget package from Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite of my Xamarin.Android Project from my Xamarin.Forms app and it turns out that the v119.7 Deprecated the InterstitialAds class to make it an abstract InterstitialAds which in order to implement I gotta inherit from that class and Implement this new abstract class.

The problem is that the method properties shown in this new class, I havent been able to figure them out yet, I havent found documentation on how to migrate from v119.6 to v119.7 for Xamarin.Forms or C#.

At Google Developer center you can find documentation on how to achieve it by using Java or Kotlin languages, but there isnt documentation on C#.

And I havent found tutorials or documentation to do it for Xamarin.Forms concretely on the Android Project which is the one affected by this update.

I know that the MOST popular asnwer might be to use Marc Troncone Admob plugin, but I wish to be able to do it without using a plugin.

has anyone here has been able to successfully update to v119.7 and apply the new way to load ads with it?

hopefully you could share your code or sample link in order to learn and master it.

Update:

```
using Android.Gms.Ads;
public class DroidInterstitialAdsService : IAdInterstitialService
{
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    public DroidInterstitialAdsService()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Platform.CurrentActivity);
    }

    async Task<bool> LoadAdAsync(string adUnitId)
    {
        var displayTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var adListener = new DroidAdListener(interstitialAd)
        {
            AdLoaded = () =>
            {
                if (displayTask != null)
                    displayTask.TrySetResult(interstitialAd.IsLoaded);
                displayTask = null;
            },
            AdFailed = () => 
            {
                if (displayTask != null)
                    displayTask.TrySetResult(interstitialAd.IsLoaded);
                displayTask = null;
            }
        };
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.AdUnitId = adUnitId;
        interstitialAd.AdListener = adListener;
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
        
        await Task.WhenAll(displayTask.Task);
        return interstitialAd.IsLoaded;
    }

    public async Task<bool> ShowAd(string adUnitId) => await LoadAdAsync(adUnitId);
}
```

That code the InterstitialAds works great if I kept the v119.6, but as soon as I update to v119.7 the class Android.Gms.Ads.InterstitialAd get deprecated.

So in order to be able to use InterstitialAds in v119.7 you gotta use this namespace:

```
using Android.Gms.Ads.Interstitial.InterstitialAd
public class DroidInterstitialAd : InterstitialAd
{
    public override string AdUnitId => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override Android.Gms.Ads.FullScreenContentCallback FullScreenContentCallback { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public override Android.Gms.Ads.IOnPaidEventListener OnPaidEventListener { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public override Android.Gms.Ads.ResponseInfo ResponseInfo => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void SetImmersiveMode(bool p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Show(Activity p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

but I dont how to implement the abstract class in order to successfully LoadAds, there isnt documentation for Xamarin.Forms or more precisely Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: can you please provide some (or any) specific example of the problems you're having?

Comment: I added more information in the question hopefully this help to ilustrate my problem.

Comment: I'm also flummoxed as to how to get 119.7 working. I have no ads on my app at all since upgrading. The https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial-fullscreen talks about the load() method but it doesn't exist, so I'm blocked almost immediately.

Comment: I had to roll back to v119.6 for now, but there must be a way to make it work for v119.7, I havent sit down to work on it. Since apparently no one does. I guess its up to Us find a solution that work with v119.7 and higher versions.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly the same thing, rolling back to v119.6. Frustrating!